# Should it be "had no reason" or "had no reason to" in the following?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Should he read the letter? He had no reason (to) other than the fact
> that it had his name on it.

Should it be "had no reason" or "had no reason to"? And why?

Comment: Please leave a source where you got this.

Comment: @Riolku I wrote it myself. Should I mention that?

Comment: Sure, that's probably preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll say that the "to" is dropped often but it sounds most correct when you leave it in.

"He had no reason other than it wasn't good" sounds fine, but:

> He had no reason to read it

> He had no reason read it

This illustrates a better example where "to" is necessary.

The "to" introduces the reason. Even on its own, when the reason is omitted, you need to include the "to":

> He had no reason to (do it)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!